# [Loading Log... Completed]

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

---

**[Analyzing and Running Script... Completed]

[Establishing Connection... Completed]

[Loading Log... Completed]

[29/03/2020 16:28:39:823]

[Log Entry #1023]

[Day #734]**

Well this is just typical. My brother, Otet, has ditched me. The one day it really mattered. Never had much backbone, he did. Can't even see me off when I move to Bosnia!

He didn't even pick up his phone when I called. But then how many of these entries have involved me saying that now...

**[Connection Discontinued]**

---

**[Connection Reestablished]**

**[29/03/2020 16:58:10:519]

[Log Entry #1023 continued]

[Day #734]**

Okay, this is a change. My brother's wife Ella is apologizing! That's a first for me. Strange she doesn't know where he is either. Oh, but she sent me a picture from him. Said that he asked her to send me it if he couldn't make my farewell. Hang on, should only take a couple of minutes to download.

**[Connection Discontinued]**

---

**[Connection Reestablished]**

**[29/03/2020 19:24:43:823]

[Log Entry #1023 continued]

[Day #734]**

Well that took a *tiny* bit longer than I thought it would. Anyway here it is:

[image: QR]

It's a QR Code. Don't know why he sent me that. I don't have the technology to scan it, and even if I did I <sub>probably wouldn't</sub> <sub><sub>be able to figure out</sub></sub> <sub><sub><sub>how to do so...</sub></sub></sub>

**[Connection Discontinued]**

---

**[Connection Reestablished]**

**[30/03/2020 17:47:01:238]

[Log Entry #1024]

[Day #735]**

Okay this is worrying. Otet hasn't turned up. I've had to cancel my move, and help the police to try and find him. I'm scared. I have no idea where he is and what's happened to him. I'm going to upload this to a puzzling website which might be able to hope.

They're my last hope...

---

**[Analyzing and Running Script... Completed]

[Retrieving Website Destination "*puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/ask*"... Completed]

[Exporting Log Entries #1023 - #1024... Completed]**

**[Connection Discontinued]**

---

**[Connection Reestablished]**
**[Uploading "*NOTE FROM OP*"... Completed]**

> **NOTE** - This puzzle is not based on true events. 
>   
>   Hints for remaining clues:

1:

> Are you sure this is completely written in English?

2:

> Why Bosnia?

3:

> WHAT DIDN'T TRANSFER WHEN YOU DECODED THE CIPHER? (Big hint in that question)

**[Connection Discontinued]**

---

Comment: Was trying to do something a bit different here. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Wow really interesting! Let's see if we can find Otet!

Comment: I appreciate the work you put into this, but most of it was just following a chain of directions. The puzzle itself is only a slight improvement of the "binary of base64 of Morse of `HI`" puzzle type. (Love the presentation though!)

Comment: @Deusovi, okay In that case I'll try and improve my puzzles for the next few. You can probably tell I was focuses mainly on presentation here :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: Don't get me wrong, I enjoyed this one! Just saying that it was a bit too simple.

Comment: Seems like you are a robot....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The QR code, when scanned, gives

> a link to [a steganography page](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/steganography/steganography.php) and the text "This is a cover image".

Using that link on the image gives

> a link to https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RUxw.jpg. This is a PDF417 code, hiding the text "Pyvpx rqvg xrl = `ebgngr`", which is ROT13 for "Click edit key = `rotate`".

That leads us to

> a HTML comment hidden in the post, Vigenere ciphered with key "rotate".

It says:

> "please don’t worry, uncle brian is taking care of me. couldn’t face telling ella. left her some money though. let me know when you can come around. and bring a couple of drinks with you! really trusting you here, don’t let me down."

In that last one,

> there are no capital letters. The capital letters *should* be:
>
>  Please
>  Uncle
>  Brian
>  Couldn't
>  Ella
>  Left
>  Let
>  And
>  Really
>
>  Together, these spell "PUB CELLAR".

Also, an easter egg:

"Otet" is Bosnian for "hijacked" or "kidnapped".

Comment: ahh, good job! I had found the page with the cover image, and the vigenere cipher while looking at the edit page.  A bit too fast for me.

Comment: Lol, I was thinking that was anew QR code and I was trying to reconstruct it xDD

Comment: Very good indeed, well done

Comment: Every other answer would just be a dupe.... +1

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: Yes, that's what happens when a question is answered fully.

Comment: @Deusovi You didn't get me; I meant your answer would be the only one possible; the question was too narrow... and by "fully", you mean every question the post asks? What about additional information provided by an "answer that extends another answer" to make the existing answer more helpful?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: That's *a good thing*. Questions *shouldn't* be too open to debate. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion board. Why do you think it should always be useful to add another answer?

Comment: @Deusovi Anyways, your answer got a +1, I can't give +2s yet.

Comment: Actually you've missed a few things, try Otet and Bosnia in google translate and look at the capitals in the last paragraph

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil: What about now?

Comment: @Deusovi Bingo! Well done.